# MethodAccessException when connecting to Oracle

Tags: oracle, silverlight, sharepoint, methodaccessexception

When I am trying to connect to the db(Oracle 11), I have an exception MethodAccessException.

```
System.MethodAccessException was unhandled by user code
  Message=Методу "e4.a(Int32)", прозрачному для безопасности, не удалось получить доступ к критически важному методу безопасности "System.Threading.Thread.Abort()".
  StackTrace:
       в e4.a(Int32 A_0)
       в e4.a(Int32 A_0, String A_1, Int32 A_2)
       в lx.a(String A_0, String A_1, String A_2, String A_3)
       в fs.b(em A_0, Boolean A_1)
       в fs.jh(em A_0, o9 A_1)
       в nl..ctor(em A_0, nl A_1)
       в el.h5(cg A_0, Object A_1, DbConnectionBase A_2)
       в sz.a(or A_0, cg A_1, DbConnectionBase A_2)
       в ny.a(or A_0, DbConnectionBase A_1)
       в or.a(DbConnectionBase A_0)
       в or.b(DbConnectionBase A_0)
       в sz.c(DbConnectionBase A_0)
       в am.ba(DbConnectionBase A_0)
       в Devart.Common.DbConnectionBase.Open()
       в Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleConnection.Open()
       в Devart.Data.Oracle.Linq.Provider.OracleDataProvider.Initialize(Object connection)
       в Devart.Data.Linq.DataProvider.Devart.Data.Linq.Engine.IProvider.Initialize(IDataServices dataServices, Object connection)
       в Devart.Data.Linq.DataContext.a(Object A_0, MappingSource A_1, Type A_2)
       в Devart.Data.Linq.DataContext..ctor(String connectionString, MappingSource mapping)
       в ITContext.ITDataContext..ctor()
       в SLWP.MainPage.Button_Click_1(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
       в System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick()
       в System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick()
       в System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
       в System.Windows.Controls.Control.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(Control ctrl, EventArgs e)
       в MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr unmanagedObj, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, Int32 argsTypeIndex, Int32 actualArgsTypeIndex, String eventName, UInt32 flags)
```

I'm making the web part for sharepoint 2010, using linqconnect for oracle. I read that the problem is solved by attribute [assembly: AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers], but that attribute is missing for silverlight. How do I solve this?

Comment: Per Google Translate, the error message translates to `Method "e4.a (Int32)", transparent safety, failed to gain access to mission-critical security methods "System.Threading.Thread.Abort ()".`

Comment: thx, i was trying to find english version of message but unsuccessfully

Comment: I suspect "transparent safety" isn't quite the correct technical term. Could you suggest a more appropriate translation?

Comment: i think it's "Security-Transparent Code"

Comment: Ah - thanks. Unfortunately I don't know anything about SharePoint, but I'll ask around tomorrow to see if anyone I work with has any ideas about this.

Comment: I will be grateful. On the Russian-speaking forums i could not find an answer.